# Chain rule and partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $z=f(x,y)$ and $x=e^{u}cos\, v\; $ and $y=e^{u}sin\,v\;$and $f$ have continuous second-order partial derivatives.

i. Show $$\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial{u}^2}=x^2\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{x}^2}+2xy\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}+y^2\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{x}^2}+x\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+y\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$

I'm able to show RHS excluding the mixed partial derivative. Can't figure out where that comes from. Please help.

Comment: Can you write here your calculations (at least for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$)?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial y^{2}} \frac{dy}{du}+\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x \partial y}\frac{dx}{du}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$

$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial u^2}=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u})^2+2\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u})^2+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial u^2}$

Using the definition of $x$ and $y$, the result follows.